Jdbc.newDate() in google script get wrong day of the month
Logger.log("..xx..2:"+ Jdbc.newDate(new Date("17-APR-2019 ").getTime()).getDate());

Logger.log("..xx."+new Date("17-APR-2019 ").getDate())

6:32:46 PM  Info    ..xx..2:16
6:32:46 PM  Info    ..xx.17

after using Jdbc.newDate() will get 16 Apr instead of 17 Apr
I hope can get correct date in order to save the correct date into mysql database
